# How can I resolve a collation conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am in the process of trying to move data from one database to another.  In the old database there is a column of datatype DateTime, which needs to be mapped to a new column in the new database which is of type Date.

To try and accomplish this I have written the following sql query

```
    UPDATE NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders
  SET NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,FishTracker.dbo.Landings.LandingDate) FROM FishTracker.dbo.Landings WHERE LandingHeaders.TicketNumber = FishTracker.dbo.Landings.TicketNo)
```

when executed however this produces the following error.

1 Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. SQL1.sql 2 1

Can anyone suggest a way that it might be possible to resolve this?

Thanks

The original database was written back in sqlserver 2005 , the new database was created in sqlserver 2012.  I no longer have easy access to a 2005 instance of sqlserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not on the `date` (and definitely if we assume that you really are using native types).  That leaves the `where` clause.  So, use the `COLLATE` operator:

```
UPDATE NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders lh
    SET lh.LandingDate1 = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, l.LandingDate)
                           FROM FishTracker.dbo.Landings l
                           WHERE lh.TicketNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  = ls.TicketNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                          );
```

I don't know which value is in which collation, so I just put the operator on both sides.  You should probably put the operator only the side with `lh`, the query can use an index on `Landings.TicketNo`.

EDIT:

That suggests that you have multiple values that match the `WHERE`.  The simplest method is to choose one, either using `TOP` or an aggregation function:

```
UPDATE NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders lh
    SET lh.LandingDate1 = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(DATE, l.LandingDate)
                           FROM FishTracker.dbo.Landings l
                           WHERE lh.TicketNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  = ls.TicketNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                          );
```

or

```
UPDATE NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders lh
    SET lh.LandingDate1 = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE, l.LandingDate))
                           FROM FishTracker.dbo.Landings l
                           WHERE lh.TicketNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  = ls.TicketNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                          );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon  I amended your suggestion slightly to the following;  UPDATE NewFishTrackerProfessional.dbo.LandingHeaders
    SET LandingDate1 = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, l.LandingDate)
                           FROM FishTracker.dbo.Landings l
                           WHERE TicketNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  = l.TicketNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                          );

Comment: which produced the following error;  1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. SQL2.sql 1 1   I suspect that this may be because there are some 106,00 rows in the table and I need to update each one.  Should I be trying to wrap your suggestion in some sort of loop?